# Make menu like chrome webstore items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How to make menu like chrome webstore item like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home

A menu with a sliding effect information show up on hover ?

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn jQuery ! Its the easiest tool you can use to make that. I assume you have moderate knowledge of HTML, CSS ans JavaScript. Or learn copying, copy the whole website and change according to your need.

Comment: I know jQuery basic.., but That I just want to search is a library or existing components that I can modify.. Do you have references?